# How can you enable cookies using Flutter's InAppWebView Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies, webview

Hello I'm wondering how do you enable cookies using flutter's inAppWebView I can imagine that it's using the property 'initialData' of this same widget but I can't figure out how to make it work properly.

Using flutter_webview It's very easy you just need to use the property as follows:

```
 WebView(
   initialCookies: [
      WebViewCookie(
         name: cookieName,
         value: cookieVal,
         domain: cookieDomain,
         path: cookiePath,
     ),
   ],
),
```

But using inAppWebView it doesn't seem as easy, I really appreaciate any help with this issue thank you in advance.

PS: The reason I need to use inAppWebView is because the url has to be parsed into an uri which is an action the normal WebView doesn't achieve as the initialUrl takes a String and the url I require has spaces that produces the webview to stay blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was very simple.
The solution was to use the same flutter Webview(Not flutter InAppWebview) package and replace the spaces of the url String with "%20" so that the url passes through Webview correctly without needing to parse the String as a Uri.